# R - Overlay multiple least squares plots with colour coding

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to visualize some data that looks like this

```
line1 <- data.frame(x = c(4, 24), y = c(0, -0.42864), group = "group1")
line2 <- data.frame(x = c(4, 12 ,24), y = c(0, 2.04538, 3.4135), group = "group2")
line3 <- data.frame(x = c(4, 12, 24), y = c(0, 3.14633, 3.93718), group = "group3")
line4 <- data.frame(x = c(0, 3, 7, 12, 18), y = c(0, -0.50249, 0.11994, -0.68694, -0.98949), group = "group4")
line5 <- data.frame(x = c(0, 3, 7, 12, 18, 24), y = c(0, -0.55753, -0.66006, 0.43796, 1.38723, 3.17906), group = "group5")

df <- do.call(rbind, list(line1, line2, line3, line4, line5))
```

What I'm trying to do is plot the least squares line (and points) for each group on the same plot. And I'd like the colour of the lines and points to correspond to the group.

All I've been able to do is plot the points according to their group

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y, colour = group)) + geom_point(aes(size = 10))
```

But I have no idea how to add in the lines as well and make their colours correspond to the points that they are fitting.

I'd really appreciate any help with this. It's turning out to be so much harder than I though it would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a `geom_smooth` layer to your plot

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y, colour = group)) + geom_point(aes(size = 10)) + 
                                               geom_smooth(method="lm",se=FALSE)
```

`method="lm"` specifies that you want a linear model

`se=FALSE`  to avoid plotting confidence intervals

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much? Do you happen to know why the lines don't extend fully? They seem to be line segments.

Comment: The segments only go from minimum to maximum value per group. For example in group1, minimum is 4 and maximum is 24. To get a full line, add a parameter inside`geom_smooth`: `fullrange=TRUE`